# Android sensors performance on NDK vs Java

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, android-sensors, android-ndk-r5

I'm trying to evaluate the pros and cons of using NDK for accessing android sensors. I found some information on internet that android sensors can be accessed by NDK apps as well as Java apps. However, is there any performance advantage of using NDK over Java? Or are there any other advantages/disadvantages I should be considering? Also, is there any portability problem in case of NDK-based app or it can run on any android device like a regular Java app?

Comment: See [this forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/mz-fj-8vTr0), there's a comment by Menion that compares two measurements. In terms of sensor outputs, I don't believe it will make a difference. Calculations with the measurements? Depends on the calculations.

Comment: Just a follow up question - Are there any other disadvantages of using NDK for accessing sensors? I know it increases the complexity in terms of writing the code, but is there any other criteria for comparison?

Comment: If the actual behind the scenes implementation of how the data for a particular sensor is obtained from the platform is in Java (as it is for a surprising number of things on Android), then dealing with the data in native code would mean the overhead of yet another trip through the jni mechanism.